# Coldfusion remote server Monitoring

Tags: coldfusion, monitoring, coldfusion-9, administration, cfadmin

We have 5 servers running on the same network.  We have already enabled ColdFusion server monitoring on the local server. Is there a way I can see the status of all remote machines - on one machine - just like SeeFusion?

The Admin API giving us this much freedom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Server Manager](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Working+with+Server+Manager) powered by [Adobe AIR](https://get.adobe.com/air/)

> **Monitor multiple servers**
>
> Server Manager provides different views to monitor servers that you
>   register with the application. To toggle between these views, click
>   the required view icon from the upper-right corner.

Comment: it does: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSfd7453be0f56bba4-2a6b48f122a6582c7f-8000.html